# Rendering Performance ffmpeg of JAVACV on Android

Tags: android, video, javacv

I am doing an application that creates a video using a set of photos saved in the sd-card. The problem I am trying to fix is that the application crashes when I create some videos. The crashes depends of the resolution of the source picture files. For example, I can render a video using 400 images with a resolution of 320x480 but I can only do a 25-frames video using images with a resolution of 2500x3200.

I am doing the rendering process in background using Asynctask (for providing a feedback to the user and maintain it informed of the rendering process). When the rendering process crashes no warnings/errors/etc are captured in the logcat. Using the DDMS for examining the memory usage I can not view any memory leak (I also do not recieve any memory warning on the logcat).  For this reasons I supose that it may be a problem related with the ffmpeg libraries (but I have no idea).

I have testet different codecs defined on avcodec.java, like:

```
AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO = 1,
AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO = 2,
      AV_CODEC_ID_H263 = 5,
     AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG = 8,
```

etc

Trying with lossless video codecs seems not doing effect, and I also get some errors when I try with some codecs.

I am running my application on a Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc (1ghz cpu, 320mb intern memory).

I do not know if my smartphone has enough power to render a long HD video, but I see that in the market there are some app's like [Droid Timelapse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Nishant.Singh.DroidTimelapse&hl=ca) that can do it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated I have no idea how can I fix that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I have found the solution, but not the originating problem.

To create the video I was using a sort of code like:

```
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(name,width,heigth);
    recorder.start()

    while(imagesinfolder){

    IplImage img = highgui.cvLoadImage("/path/to/image[i].jpg")
    recorder.record(img)
    i++;
    }
```

It seems to create a memory problem, maybe because IplImage is not cleaned by the garbage collector.

My solution is use, instead of highgui.cvLoadImage, the method: opencv_core.cvLoadImage(img); and then,  opencv_core.cvReleaseImage(img); in every iteration.

```
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(name,width,heigth);
recorder.start()

while(imagesinfolder){

IplImage img = opencv_core.cvLoadImage("/path/to/image[i].jpg")
recorder.record(img)
img.cvReleaseImage();
i++;
}
```

Using it, all the poblems have disappeared and I can render long videos witout any issues.